# C++ String individual characters

Tags: c++, string, hash, modulo

I'm trying to make a function that takes the first and last letters of a string, divides them for the modulus and stores them in an array spot related to the modulus number. However I don't know how I would get the first and last letters of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the first letter of your string by just using `yourString[0]` and to get the last latter you can use `yourString[yourString.size()-1]`

**EDIT**

As said in the comments, assuming you're using std::string

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `std::string str`, you can use either:

- [`str.front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) and [`str.back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) (C++11 and later only).
- `str[0]` and `str[str.size()-1]`, if `str` is not empty.